# MailKit IMAP - return the email date, the email size and then a method to delete

Tags: mailkit

I have the following that downloads mail...

```
Using vClient As New ImapClient(New ProtocolLogger("C:\Temp\imap3.log"))
vClient.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect)
vClient.Authenticate(vT2)
vClient.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite)
vNumber = vClient.Inbox.Count
If vNumber > 0 Then

    Using wr As New StreamWriter("C:\Temp\EmailMessages.txt", True)
        ' vClient.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly)
        Dim UIDS = vClient.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All)
        Dim vItems = vClient.Inbox.Fetch(UIDS, MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate Or MessageSummaryItems.Flags)
        For i As Integer = 0 To UIDS.Count - 1
            Dim vAttachments As Integer = 0
            Dim Message = vClient.Inbox.GetMessage(i)
            Dim vSubject As String = Message.Subject
            If vSubject = "" Then
                vSubject = "No Subject"
            End If
            Dim vBody As String = Message.HtmlBody
            If vBody = "" Then
                vBody = "No message was included"
            End If
            Dim vSender As String = Message.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault().Address
            Dim vSenderName As String = Message.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault().Name

            Dim vSize As String = MessageSummaryItems.Size
            Dim vTempDate As String = MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate
            Message.WriteTo(String.Format("{0}.eml", i))
            vMessage = Message.ToString
            ' wr.WriteLine(vMessage)
            Dim vInboxID As Integer = 0
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Mail_Inbox (Inbox_From, Inbox_Subject, Inbox_Body, Inbox_SenderName, Inbox_Size, Inbox_TempDate, Inbox_Content) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vSender & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(vSubject) & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitHTML(vBody) & "',"
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(vSenderName) & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & vSize & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(vTempDate) & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitHTML(vMessage) & "')"
            vInboxID = InsertDataReturnID_Data(strSQL, 0, "238", True)

            For Each attachment As MimeEntity In Message.Attachments
                Dim vFilename = If(attachment.ContentDisposition?.FileName, attachment.ContentType.Name)
                Dim vByte() As Byte = Nothing
                Using vStream As New MemoryStream
                    If TypeOf attachment Is MessagePart Then
                        Dim rfc822 = CType(attachment, MessagePart)
                        rfc822.Message.WriteTo(vStream)
                        vByte = vStream.ToArray

                    Else
                        Dim vPart = CType(attachment, MimePart)
                        vPart.Content.DecodeTo(vStream)
                        vByte = vStream.ToArray
                    End If
                    If InsertEmailAttachment(vByte, vInboxID, vFilename) = False Then
                        'There was an error here
                    End If
                End Using
                vAttachments += 1
            Next
            If vAttachments > 0 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE Mail_Inbox SET Flag_Attachment = '" & vAttachments & "' WHERE Inbox_ID = " & vInboxID
                InsertData_Data(strSQL, 0, "278", True)
            End If

            ' vClient.Inbox.AddFlags(UniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, True)

        Next

    End Using
End If
vClient.Disconnect(True)
End Using
```

Ignore the StreamWriter (just used initially to test, it now writes to a DB)

There are three items I am trying to format. The date of the email, the size of the email and a method to delete everything on the server once they have been downloaded.

I can see that the dates are being fetched...

```
C: A00000007 UID FETCH 2,5,8,12,15,37,40 (FLAGS INTERNALDATE)
S: * 1 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "01-Feb-2024 08:16:36 +0000" UID 2)
S: * 2 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "01-Feb-2024 15:15:02 +0000" UID 5)
S: * 3 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "01-Feb-2024 16:44:16 +0000" UID 8)
S: * 4 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "02-Feb-2024 07:57:12 +0000" UID 12)
S: * 5 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "24-Feb-2024 13:53:39 +0000" UID 15)
S: * 6 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "25-Feb-2024 08:02:54 +0000" UID 37)
S: * 7 FETCH (FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "25-Feb-2024 13:48:07 +0000" UID 40)
S: A00000007 OK FETCH completed.
```

But the data I am getting for all the records is inbox_size = 64 and Inbox_Date (as string) = 32

I tried a few variations of Inbox.AddFlags(UniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, True) to delete all the records once they are downloaded but can't get the syntax right.

Other than that, everything else works.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Dim Message = vClient.Inbox.GetMessage(i)
```

to this:

```
Dim Message = vClient.Inbox.GetMessage(vItems[i].UniqueId)
```

Then, to get strings representing the size and date, change these lines:

```
Dim vSize As String = MessageSummaryItems.Size
Dim vTempDate As String = MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate
```

to this:

```
Dim vSize As String = vItems[i].Size
Dim vTempDate As String = vItems[i].InternalDate
```

Then, to delete the message, change this line:

```
vClient.Inbox.AddFlags(UniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, True)
```

to this:

```
vClient.Inbox.AddFlags(vItems[i].UniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response - the date is now working perfectly, but size is giving me grief - even parsing for a null object is throwing object reference not set which is really baffling. In the meantime, I have marked the answer up.

Comment: Size always returns null/nothing - is this usual for Exhange online?

Comment: Size I can return from the DB, but delete isn't working as intended - perhaps it's a soft delete and just sets a flag - but the same emails are downloading again. Is there a way to hard delete? Most mail clients have a 'remove from server when downloaded' method and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm thinking that adding  vClient.Inbox.Expunge() before disconnect will totally remove them?

Comment: Size is always `null` in your code because you aren't asking the server for the Size in your Fetch request. Use `MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate Or MessageSummaryItems.Flags Or MessageSummaryItems.Size` in your Fetch request

Comment: IMAP uses a 2-step delete. First you need to set the Deleted flag and then you need to EXPUNGE. @gchq is correct - you need to use vClient.Inbox.Expunge() before disconnecting.

Comment: Bearing in mind that I am used to Domino Server and Notes Client - if I use the Notes Client to connect to an outside mailbox (say IONOS) it's set to download and delete from the server. If I open the email in the client it sends a read report (if requested). Using Inbox.Expunge after downloading mails causes the server to send a 'deleted without being read' reply to the sender. Is there a way to overcome that behaviour? I know that I can mark the flags as 'read' first, but that will only cause the server to send an incorrect read report.

Comment: That's something you'd have to ask someone more familiar with Domino's implementation of the read receipt feature (or perhaps their documentation if it explains this type of scenario).

Comment: Sorry - didn't explain that very well - the connection is to Outlook Online. It's just that for the last few decades Domino/Notes is all I have used so 365 is a new learning curve.

Comment: My answer is unfortunately still more-or-less the same - read receipts is a server-specific feature that is not related to IMAP, so there's no way to control the behavior via the IMAP protocol. That said, I don't really understand what you want the server to do. If you mark it as \Seen first, it sends "message read", but if you delete it w/o \Seen, then it sends "message deleted w/o being read". I guess you want it to send nothing? Sounds like that's not possible.

Comment: Jeff - sorry I just refined the question and reposted it. If I download a message from an internet server using Notes Client, it deletes it from the server. When the client opens it, it then sends a read receipt. Perhaps the answer is that most internet mail servers do not honour read receipts, but Exhange (like Domino) does?

Comment: Probably? I don't know.